# Buy credits using In-App purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

What my requirement is?

I want to implement the In-App purchase functionality in app.

I will add some In-App purchase in app like below:
Buy 50 Credits: $0.99

Buy 200 Credits: $1.99

Buy 400 Credits: $2.99

So, suppose user buy the 50 Credits in $0.99.

And after some days suppose, after 10 days, user uses all these 50 credits. And he wants to buy more credits. Then he is purchased 200 credits in $1.99.

We can tract that user uses all his credits and we will ask to user to buy more credits.

But what type of In-App purchase will be better for that?

Suppose, I implement "Consumable" In App purchase.
Then I think there will be some time period like 1 month, 2 month, 3 month. And then user has to buy the feature again.

But in my case, we don't know, when user will use his credits. like user can use all credits in 10 days. OR user can use all credits in 2 months.

So, we ask to user to pay for more credits once he complete his existing credits.

I hope it will be enough to understand.

Has any one idea how can I achieve this InApp purchase?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consumable is the correct approach. It is not true that user will have to buy after a specified interval of time.
He can buy credits whenever he wants, you just need to keep adding his current credits when he buys them, and keep deducting them when he uses them.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You mean that, if we implement In-App as consumable, then every time user will have to Pay for it. Right? And after successful payment, we just add the credits to user account. And if credit goes to 0 then we force fully asked to user to buy credits. Is it like so? So, finally consumable is not based on time. And user has to buy the credits every time and he will be charged for same. right? And are you sure about this? Once again thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Yes you understood it correctly, consumable has nothing to do with time.